# Why is my NSString variable outputting "1" when using ofstream?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is what I have so far:

```
minute++;//this code is in a for loop where this variable is being incremented
NSString *minuteString;

NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YY"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];

if(minute < 10){
    minuteString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 00:0%d:00",dateString,minute];
}
if(minute > 10){

    minuteString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 00:%d:00",dateString, minute];
}

ofs << minuteString << ",";
```

When I use `NSLog(@"%@",minuteString)`, the correct string is outputted. However, when the stream outputs to the CSV file I have setup, the output is the number 1. I am not sure why this is occurring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because C++ std::ofstream can not handle ObjectiveC classes.
You need to convert NSString to std::string to be able to use ofstream. Something like:

```
std::string std_str([ ns_str UTF8String ] ) ;
ofs << std_str;
```

std::ofstream is from the standard C++ library. NSString is from ObjectiveC library. Different libraries and different programming languages. They weren't designed to work together. You can mix these things in your code because your compiler understands them, but you need to provide a bridge. It is a good idea to mix languages together on a library level, not on a lower level. That is if you have one cleanly separated piece of functionality implemented in ObjectiveC (e.g. GUI) and another in C++ (e.g. game physics, business logic) then you create a thin layer to pass data between libraries. Otherwise, use a single language.